# R: Convert Sys.now() to epoch timestamp with microseconds

Tags: r, posixct

I want to convert current time to epoch timestamp with microseconds in R. For that I am running following code.

```
options(digits.secs = 6)
now = Sys.time()    
as.double(now)
```

When I simply print `now` the output is `"2017-11-11 20:40:18.370305 CET"` where it is capturing microseconds but when I convert it to epoch timestamp using `as.double(now)`, the microsecond precision is gone. The result is only `1510429218`. How to retain the microseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do (always) have them, but you need to tell `print` to use more digits:

```
R> n <- Sys.time()
R> print(as.numeric(n), digits=16)    ## digits matters here
[1] 1510432192.721936
R> n
[1] "2017-11-11 14:29:52.721935 CST"
R>
```

Answer (score 1):

Learned how R handles decimal digits very hard way! See following code.

```
options(digits.secs = 6)    
a = c(as.double(Sys.time()), as.double(Sys.time()), as.double(Sys.time()))
print(a)
```

The output of this code is following.

```
[1] 1510430216 1510430216 1510430216
```

Timestamps seem to have lost their microsecond precision. But when the data is written to file or exported it the decimal digits are visible.

```
df = data.frame(a)
write.csv(x = df, file = "test.csv")
```

Contents of the file are:

```
1 1510430215.888998
2 1510430215.889942
3 1510430215.889942
```

To also see the decimal digits in R session/console, visibility options need to be changed.

```
options(digits = 16)
print(a)
```

Now all the decimal digits are visible in R session too!

```
[1] 1510430215.888998 1510430215.889942 1510430215.889942
```

The default display digits are only 7. So if the number is greater than that, R simply chooses to discard decimal digits from displaying! It is ridiculous as it creates massive confusion. At least one or two decimal digits should be kept.